# I want to run an Event Observer once after my custom module is installed

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, custom

Is there a way to run a function (to call an api) once after a module is installed? It could be during admin page load or in the install script. But i wish to run only once. Thanks

Comment: hey did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use Install script because of **InstallSchema** code is run one time.

So, on your extension, you have to write `InstallSchema.php` which is located at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Setup`..

See how to create install scheme Look this block:https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-and-upgrade-database-in-magento-2/

Comment: thanks. But it does not work. I tried to do some action on the **install** function but it does not do anything.